# JustifyLeft, Right and Center doesn't function in ckeditor toolbar when added in menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, ckeditor4.x, justify

I tried the same approach as mentioned in the stackoverflow question : [CKEditor 4.7 - Justify Group Menu Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283793/ckeditor-4-7-justify-group-menu-button)

I could see justify left, right and center options available in the menu (dropdown), but when clicked on any of the buttons nothing works .

The same worked when I added any one of the Justify buttons ( left or right or center ) to the toolbar.

Can someone please help me in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this issue by adding "allowedcontent:true" configuration to disable automatic ACF, whereas this might pose an issue with unsecure content being added to editor.
refer this link for more information : https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/acf.html